# Fulltext indexes vs pattern_ops indexes

Tags: django, postgresql, indexing, django-queryset, full-text-indexing

I am using django, and all of my queries are created by django, so i have no handwritten queries...

I have a table of `BillRecords`, which has a field `subscriberno` . In my django filters, i use a filtering query like:

```
BillRecords.objects.filter(subscriberno__icontains='123456')
```

Since the `subscriberno` the customer said might be quite shortened version of the real number...

That filter outputs a query like:

```
SELECT "subscriberno" FROM "BillRecords" WHERE UPPER("subscriberno"::text) LIKE UPPER(E'%123456%');
```

`subscriberno` is a char field because some numbers contains alphas and some special chars.

On my database, i have two indexes for that column, created by my colleagues.

```
"BillRecords_subscriberno" btree (subscriberno)
"BillRecords_fsubscriberno_like" btree (subscriberno varchar_pattern_ops)
```

**I am wondering** using two indexes for a such query is logical. Since all of our django filter uses `icontains` and that supposed to be create queries like i write above.

Postgres analyse of the query is as follows:

```
Seq Scan on BillRecords  (cost=0.00..159782.40 rows=370 width=15) (actual time=579.637..3705.079 rows=10 loops=1)
Filter: (upper((subscriberno)::text) ~~ '%123456%'::text)
Total runtime: 3705.106 ms
(3 rows)
```

So, as far as i see, no index is used. Since index usega have costs in data insertion and update, having two indexes with no usage (as far as i can see from this analyse)  seemed me not logical.

Is there any channce for django to output different queries for a similar `icontanis` filter? Or my indexes are totally useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an index on an unanchored like statement.

```
upper(foo) like 'bar%' -- index on upper(foo)
upper(foo) like '%bar' -- no index
reverse(upper(foo)) like 'rab%' -- index on reverse(upper(foo))
upper(foo) like '%bar%' -- no index
```

But you might find the [trigram contrib](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) of use, if you want to reduce the search window.

Answer (score 1):

Contains (substring) queries do not have access to indexes (unless the operator is linked to a full-text module). Starts-with queries on the other hand can benefit from indexes. Indexing overhead is negligible if the cardinality is not too low and inserts typically are not made in large batches but in an OLTP scenario.

Do I read the stats correctly: almost 4 seconds to scan 370 rows?

P.S. You might consider an alternative approach: using a function-based index, perhaps on the last four characters of subscriberno concatenated to, say, the first three characters of the subscribername, and using starts-with or equals instead of LIKE with the search-term bookended with wildcards.

Comment: Actually PostgreSQL 9.1 will be able to use an index for "contains" queries using `like '%foo%'`. See here: http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Right-o. I should have added (unless...linked to a full-text module `or some other kind of string tokenizer`).

Comment: I can not use subscriber name ): all i have in hand is __subscriberno__, this is a kind of "system that holds info about different subscription types", so i have a variety of different subscription formats and some formatting is applied to a few of them...

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to check if your indexes are used at all is to look at

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_indexes;
```

If all your queries are like the one you show, then they certainly won't be used, because the pattern is not anchored.  If you want to address that, you will have to re-engineer your search a bit by using full-text search, trigrams, or something like that.